# Cache and Spring MVC with Tiles

Tags: spring, caching, tiles

I'm going to use cache using txt files. I want to save current tamplate name in there. And so... Should I do something special? Is it easy as simple console Java programm which returns line from txt? My txt is locating in webapp directory, but not in web-inf. Is it ok?
Give me advices.

Comment: Why you want to save the current template in cache??

Comment: Because I'll read this on each peage(often read,almost unchanged)